# How to remove particular special characters alone from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a string like below,

> Hindustan Times, Oct 2009, Review by a
>   well known Art critic on her solo
>   exhibition at Jaipur, Jawahar Kala
>   Kendra'th, 23-29th Sep 2009. "Many of
>   her paintings including her self
>   portrait, stress in humanities
>   singular plight and aimlessness"

In the above string I need to remove the following characters

`,` `"` `'` `-` `.`

Are there any string functions I can use to remove these characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can opt to strip out all characters that *aren't* alphanumeric or spaces, instead of listing all the characters you don't want:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/", "", $str);
```

Of course, this would strip out **all** punctuation, and perhaps more characters than you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace an array of characters

```
$str = "Hindustan Times, Oct 2009, Review by a well known Art critic on her solo exhibition at Jaipur, Jawahar Kala Kendra'th, 23-29th Sep 2009. \"Many of her paintings including her self portrait, stress in humanities singular plight and aimlessness";
$search     = array(',', '"', "'", '-', '.');
$clean      = str_replace($search, ' ', $str); 
echo $clean;
```

Comment: It helps that I suck at regex ^_^

Answer (score 0):

use preg_replace , and replace the set you want with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

[JohnP has the right way with using `str_replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092990/how-to-remove-get-characters-alone-in-a-string-in-php/6093027#6093027). The rule of thumb is basically only use a regex where other string methods won't do (or at least not nicely).

However, if you want to use a regex, you could do that too.

You would enter those characters in a character class, taking note to escape the string delimiter and also to use `-` in a manner where it will be taken literally, not as a range.

```
preg_replace('/[,"\'.-]+/', '', $str);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/bYXsN).

Comment: That will select any character - the `.` will match any character.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Not in a character class.